# Sed remove character at beginning of string

Tags: regex, bash, nginx, sed

I have the following script which inserts a "#" before a IP-address in a nginx config to act as a comment.

```
#!/bin/bash
hosts=( 84.19.155.71 84.19.155.72 )
for i in "${hosts[@]}"
do
        CHECK=`grep $i nginx.conf`
        if [[ ! "$CHECK" =~ ^#.*$ ]]
        then
                nc -zw 5 $i 5044
                if [ "$?" != "0" ]
                then
                        sed -i "/$i/s/^/#/" nginx.conf
                else
                        sed -i 's/#*$i/$i/' nginx.conf
                fi
        fi
done
```

It works to insert the "#" at the beginning of the string but now I want to remove it if the exit code of the `nc` command is 0. I tried it with my else statement as shown above but to no avail. This is what the `nginx.conf` looks like:

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so;


worker_rlimit_nofile 1000000;

events {
        worker_connections 20000;
        # multi_accept on;
}

stream {
log_format    basic    '$time_iso8601 $remote_addr '
                       '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                       '$session_time $upstream_addr '
                       '"$upstream_bytes_sent" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_connect_time"';

# Enable access_log statements for debugging
access_log /var/log/nginx/stream.log basic;

  upstream syslog_udp {
    #hash $remote_addr;
    server 84.19.155.71:514 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=5s;
#    server 84.19.155.72:514 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=5s;
  }
  server {
    listen 514 udp;
    proxy_pass syslog_udp;
    proxy_responses 0;
    #proxy_timeout 2s;
    proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
    #proxy_next_upstream_timeout 2s;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help removing the "#" character from the IP-address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, only lines that do not begin with # are processed by the first if statement `if [[ ! "$CHECK" =~ ^#.*$ ]]`

Adding # looks fine and for removing, you could try:

```
sed -i "s/^#*$i//" nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

> if [[ ! "$CHECK" =~ ^#.*$ ]] this will take only lines which doesnt start with "#"
>   you may have to revisit that part which i will not discuss.

But here is the sed replace which might help you.

```
user@machine:$cat sample 
server 84.19.155.71:514 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=5s;
#server 84.19.155.72:514 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=5s;

user@machine:$sed  "s/^#\(.*$i.*\)/\1/g" sample
server 84.19.155.71:514 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=5s;
server 84.19.155.72:514 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=5s;
```

Comment: This works just as well as the solution above, Thank you very much!